# property 'jquery' does not exist on type 'window & typeof globalthis'

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

trying to use jQuery on this part of my angular ts code:

```
@ViewChild("focusMe", { static: false }) MyInput: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    window.jQuery(this.MyInput.nativeElement).find('input').focus();
}
```

however the intellisense is as follows

property 'jquery' does not exist on type 'window & typeof globalthis'

how can i load JQuery onto the window?

Comment: well, if You loading jQuery somehow (via script tag in your HTML or with npm import and `angular.json` `scripts` clause import) -> just declare the jquery : `declare var jQuery` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is all about not manipulating the DOM directly, that being said if you really need jQuery then add it in your project with `npm i jquery` instead of adding it to a `script` tag, then use it like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

@ViewChild("focusMe", { static: false }) MyInput: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(this.MyInput.nativeElement).find('input').focus();
}
```

You choose the name when you import it, so if you really need `jQuery`, then use `import jQuery from 'jquery';`